# Pushing an element to an existing array stored in session storage

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props

So, I'm trying to push an element stored in session storage to an array of objects also stored in session storage.

Here is what I tried but it gives me this error (sessionStorage.getItem(...).push is not a function)

sessionStorage.getItem("items").push(sessionStorage.getItem("method"))

Answer (score 0):

You can only store strings in session storage. If you want to save an array to session storage, you must serialize it using `JSON.stringify()` and then use `JSON.parse()` when reading from session storage. Also, after modifying the array you have to save it again.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]));

const items = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('items'));
items.push({ method: sessionStorage.getItem('method') });
sessionStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
```

See [demo](https://jsbin.com/navidanidi/1/edit?js,console).

Comment: But I actually stored the array of objects with using JSON.stringify like this sessionStorage.setItem("items", this.state.allItems) and when I consoled the "items" it did show on the console

Comment: @Gazzar2 So what is the problem?

Comment: the "Items" looks like this [{id: 0, name: test, quantity: 2}] and the "method" is a string like this "example". What I want to do is to push "example" to the array to make it like this [{id: 0, name: test, quantity: 2}, {method: example}]